# pgr_createtopology, can't find the right tolerance needed for my routes which is created in QGIS and imported by GDAL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis, pgrouting

I created my routes in QGIS v2.18 and tested it if it is routable or not by using the Road Graph Plugin in QGIS and as shows in the image below it is routable with my plugin's tolerance set as 0.0000 and WG:84 4326.

But when I import the shp file into postgre, and use pgr_createtopology. My paths are fragmented, I tried the following tolerances: `1.16, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001` up until 10 zeros as I had time to experiment it and yet I can't find the right tolerance needed.
[Link to the image of broken lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdvTZ.jpg)
[Link to the image from QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wir3I.jpg)

Comment: the two images are the same

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) to estimate the ground length (in meters) when using various number of degree decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using a tolerance that I used when I used the Explode Lines plugin in QGIS, Since I made the path in QGIS and tested the routes there using one of its plugins.
the right tolerance for me was 0.000034 in a 4326.
I'm not sure if this would help anyone.